# Android: Spinner shows title bar for 1/2 sec

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner, fullscreen

Currently I have set my app to be fullscreen in java rather than xml with:

```
// Full Screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.location);
```

This works fine except for one odd behavior with the spinners. When you select a spinner the title bar appears for a split second then returns to the background. Also the splash screen has this same code yet the title bar persists in that class as well. Any ideas why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

In your android manifest add 

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`

I have this in each activity i've declared in one of my apps, but you can also apply it in the lay out.

manifest excerpt:

Layout excerpt:

using the layout method, child/nested layouts should inherit this unless its overridden, by theme or style. Hope it works.

Comment: That didn't work. It seems to be occuring when its a larger spinner. The two spinners that only have a couple options don't cause the title bar to show but once I click on spinner with 20+ the title bar shows.

Comment: Then sorry, i am out of ideas :( That should have worked but ive never encountered your issue nor used that large of a spinner.